# how do I make this function generic so that it accepts any container

Tags: c++

I am strugling with the second function. I want it to be just like the first one but to accept List and vector

```
void draw__vec(vector<shape *> vs){

    for(int i=0; i< vs.size();i++){
        vs[i]->draw();
    }

}

template <typename T>
void draw_generic(T<shape *> c){

}
```

Comment: One solution would be to look into [iterators](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterator#C.2B.2B), which will allow you to traverse containers without having to rely on specific characteristics like `std::vector`'s indexing ability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way is to use iterators.

```
template <typename T>
void draw_generic(T c){
    typename T::iterator beg = c.begin(), end = c.end();

    while (beg != end) {
       (*beg)->draw();
       ++beg;
    }
}
```

Comment: It could be made more generic by taking the begin and end iterators as arguments

Comment: @Seth: It should be `typename T::iterator`, not only `T::iterator`

Comment: I have an error: i was not declared in this scope. are you sure *i can be used?

Comment: @user521180: It should be `(*beg)->draw();`.

Comment: @KerrekSB yes, feel free to correct stupid mistakes like that.

Comment: Those should probably be `const_iterators`, unless the `Draw` function is not `const`.

Answer (score 2):

To make birryree's suggestion more concrete, here's how it might look:

```
template <typename T>
void draw_generic(T begin, const T &end)
{
    while(begin != end)
    {
        (*begin)->draw();
        ++begin;
    }
}
```

Now its usage will look something like this:

```
vector<shape *> shapearray;
list<shape *> shapelist;

// do something with those shapes
// ..

draw_generic(shapearray.begin(), shapearray.end());
draw_generic(shapelist.begin(), shapelist.end());
```

Comment: Not sure what compiler you're using, but shouldn't this fail to compile?  The temporary object returned by `.begin()` should be constant.

Comment: This shouldn't work, because you're taking the iterators by reference. `begin` and `end` returns values, not references. And you cannot bind a temporary value to a non-const reference.

Comment: Yeah I just noticed, I fixed begin to take by value instead.

Answer (score 1):

more c++11-ish:

```
template <typename Container>
void Draw(Container c)
{
    for_each(begin(c), end(c), [](Shape* curr)
    {
         curr->draw();
    });
}
```

Comment: You might consider forgetting about the `for_each` + lambda when you can just write `for (Shape* curr: c) { curr->draw(); }`. It might seem that lambda makes `for_each` useful, but they also gave you a range-for loop. `for_each` continues to be the least useful algorithm in C++11 ;)